# Check Visibility of a column in iif statement for a property of another report item

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report where most things are hidden. At runtime there are a series of toggles to enable columns hidden or visible.

What I am trying to do is build an expression that will check weather a field is visible or not and change the background color of a cell to indicate that that group is selected.

I was kind of hoping that it would be as simple as

```
=iif((reportItems!Textbox55.visible = true) , "red", "yellow")
```

or possibly

```
=iif(reportItems!Textbox55.hidden, "red", "yellow")
```

but neither of these worked.

Has anyone run across this or have an idea of a work around?

EDIT!!!

this cell and toggle 
[image: This cell]

controls this columns visibility. 
[image]

I need a way to know when the column Is visible so I can apply that logic to the Background color expression on the "RFM Code toggle" cell so I can change its color

Comment: Why not centralize the logic for that hidden property and base the other item's property on that as well? That is, create a variable or parameter or field that holds the logic for that "Hidden" property, and bind both the visibility and the other item's background to it?

Comment: That sounds good but how would you determine the visibility property hidden = true of the cell?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really provided a [repro](http://sscce.org), so I'm flying a little dark here, but let me turn my comment into an answer nonetheless.

From your question it seems Visibility of "`Textbox55`" is dynamic. Let's assume it's `Hidden` property has the following expression:

```
=Iif(Parameters!ShowGroup1.Value > 10, True, False)
```

It then makes sense to set the background color of your cell to something similar, e.g.:

```
=Iif(Parameters!ShowGroup1.Value > 10, "red", "yellow")
```

If the expression is more complex (say, with many nested `Iif`s or something like that), you can move that expression to a second parameter so the logic is centralized, and have both the Visibility and background color depend on that.